# How do I get an app to show up in the Application Loader?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, ios4, app-store

I added a new App ID and distribution profile then went to iTunes Connect and added a new application from the Manage Application link-

Uploaded screenshots and the icon.

So what else do I need to do to get the app to show up in the Application Loader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application must be in the `Waiting For Upload` state.  iTunesConnect will direct you to Application Loader once you've reached this step.